# Replace a Substring of a String in Velocity Template Language

Tags: string, replace, velocity, vtl

I want to replace a part of a string in Velocity Template Language with another string.

For Example:

```
#set($a = "Hello")
#set($b = "+")
```

I want to replace ll in Hello with ++.  The output should be He++o

Please help me

Thanks
Kishore

Answer (score 79):

By default you can use the methods of the Java String object:

```
#set( $a = "Hello" )
#set( $b = $a.replace("l", "+") )
${b}
```

will produce **He++o** and you can also use velocity variables as arguments to your method calls, e.g.:

```
#set( $a = "Hello" )
#set( $b = "+" )
#set( $c = $a.replace("l", ${b}) )
${c}
```

Comment: I just want to add a little note for future visitors: I had a very simple conversion in my velocity template from ö to oe, but it seemed like it was not working. Anyway, after a while I realised the character set of input was cp-1252 and jvm was working with utf-8 so the "ü" in the template was not the "ü" I was after..

Comment: what is the purpose of the curly braces here?

Comment: @anon58192932 Curly braces are for formal notion.  In this specific example,they are not absolutely required.  $b is an identical reference as ${b}.  Link: [Apache](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.0/user-guide.html#formal-reference-notation)