# AWS Lambda Error : 'Could not parse request body into json ' when url parameter contains JSON array

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to invoke my **Lambda** function by passing parameters as below. it contains **apostrophe(')**.

```
https://invoke_url?param=[["kurlo jack's book","Adventure Books",8.8,1]]
```

Stringifyed to be 'https://invoke_url?param=%5B%5B%229780786706211%22s....`

I used the mapping below to pass parameter to lambda

```html
  "query": {
    #foreach($queryParam in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
    "$queryParam": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($queryParam))" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  }
```

I got following error

```
{"message": "Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized character escape \'\'\' (code 39)\n at [Source: [B@5b70c341; line: 29, column: 65]"}
```

i have also tried after removing double quotes from mapping template. But did't work.

Comment: Can you print the string right before it is going to be parsed?

Comment: @johni is there any way to do this on api gateway integration request maping?

Comment: There should be. I'm not an Api Gayeway expert, but from the material that I've studied the past couple of days, there seems to be support for that. Anyway, I think your problem has to do with the string that you're trying to parse. Nothing else, that does not have to do with AWS at all (IMO)

Comment: That should answer your question regarding Api Gateway http://stackoverflow.com/q/31329958/3454745

Comment: Do we have to decode the string back in json template section of API Gateway? Or it solves this internally?

Answer (score 9):

Be sure to add `.replaceAll("\\'","'")` to your request body passthrough template after `.escapeJavaScript(data)`

I found this bit from AWS's documentation to be very helpful for this issue:

> $util.escapeJavaScript()
>
> Escapes the characters in a string using JavaScript string rules.
>
> Note This function will turn any regular single quotes (') into
>   escaped ones (\'). However, the escaped single quotes are not valid in
>   JSON. Thus, when the output from this function is used in a JSON
>   property, you must turn any escaped single quotes (\') back to regular
>   single quotes ('). This is shown in the following example: 
>   `$util.escapeJavaScript(data).replaceAll("\\'","'")`

Comment: I'm trying this but I just get internal server error. ```"query": {
    #foreach($queryParam in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
    "$queryParam": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($queryParam)).replace(\"\\'\",\"'\")" #if($foreach.hasNext),#end

    #end
  }  ```

Comment: **NOTE**: If the mapping template is defined as part of a JavaScript/TypeScript string within a CDK app, you'll need to double up on the escape tokens, i.e. `$util.escapeJavaScript(data).replaceAll("\\\\'","'")`

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a solution but I have narrowed the root cause. Lambda does not seem to like single quotes to be escaped with a single slash.

If you hardcode your mapping template to look like this:

```
{
    "query-fixed": {
        "param": "[[\"kurlo jack\\'s book\",\"Adventure Books\",8.8,1]]"
    }
}
```

my test Lambda invocation succeeds. However, if you hardcode the template to this:

```
{
    "query-fixed": {
        "param": "[[\"kurlo jack\'s book\",\"Adventure Books\",8.8,1]]"
    }
}
```

I get the same error message that you got above. Unfortunately, the second variation is what API Gateway produces for the Lambda invocation.

A workaround might involve using the template to replace single quotes escaped with slash to two slashes. See [Replace a Substring of a String in Velocity Template Language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843882/replace-a-substring-of-a-string-in-velocity-template-language)

I'll follow up with Lambda internally and update if I hear anything or have a functional workaround.

Comment: it's really helped me to fix this issue. i have updated the solution in your answer

Answer (score 0):

The "query string" (the part in the hyperlink after `?`) must be a `string`. Whatever you have constructing that must be appended to it like: `https://invoke_url?a=x&b=y`

In your Lambda code put:

```
if( event.hasOwnProperty( 'params' ) )
    if( event.params.hasOwnProperty( 'querystring' ) )
        params = event.params.querystring;
```

*(obviously some extraneous checks, probably unnecessary but ehh)*

In your API Gateway go to:

`APIs -> api_name -> Resources -> invoke_url -> GET -> Method Execution`

Under URL Query String Parameters "Add query string" `a` and `b` (or whatever)

When you hit `www.com/invoke_url?a=x&b=y` you can now access them with:

```
...
params = event.params.querystring;
console.log( params.a, params.b );
...
```

Comment: Actually i am sending parameter like this : invok_url?param=%5B%5B%229780786706211%22%2C%22Endurance%3A%20Shackleton%27s%20Incredible%20Voyage%22%2C%22Adventure%20Books%22%2C8.8%2C1%5D%5D

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your encoding of `'` to %27 as per what is is defined in [this W3Schools page](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp) (ironically their example does not encodes the single quote either, I guess its because it belongs to the "supported" ASSCII set of characters)